PC setup for power users with a life on the go
I have always been into performance computing on the go. I am a student of computational science and don't have enough money to buy a powerful computer, but I want to, in the future, and I want to know how and if my setup plans work.
So, here is my master plan:
I will buy the highest end desktop setup I can and will not buy a laptop, but only a decent iphone and an ipad. I will setup my desktop as a windows server at home that serves its desktop remotely over LAN or WAN, depending on the situation. Note that I might not be near the hardware for months at a time and should work. I might mostly use my iphone as the pc interface when I am far from home - for working on data, simulations and playing AAA games, besides a bigger device like ipad if possible. Do you see any problems? Do you have any suggestions?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This question both asks for hardware recommendations and is so vague as to be a matter of opinion. Try https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ if you can be more specific.

That should be doable, with the caveat that it will increase latency (you're dependent on a fast network all the way to your PC which while plausible may not be an actuality), and the lack of peripherals is not necessarily great. It should function though and as long as the controls match what a touchscreen can do (or be assigned to such), it should function.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
